# Create XML using XMLWriter without closing tags in c#

Tags: c#, xml, xmlwriter

Is there any way of creating closing XML tags using XMLWriter in C# without having opening XML tags and vice versa?

To better explain my problem, I have written a program that I need to create an XML file that will have the following tags, for example:

```
<test>
<test1>
```

A seperate program will then append to that same file and write out data tags and then I want this same program to close the tags

```
</test> 
</test1>
```

Can this be done using XMLWriter or is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: Rule 42 of Stackoverflow, someone has probably asked before you

Comment: You probably want the closing tags inserted in the reversed order.